# TypeError: Cannot read property of 'hash' of undefined in argon2 and bcrypt

Tags: node.js, nestjs, bcrypt, argon2-ffi

I'm using Nestjs and have tried both libraries `argon2` and `bcrypt`.

`import argon2 from 'argon2'`
and `import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'`
are both causing the same error.

When I hover over `hash` in  `userDto.password = await argon2.hash(userDto.password);`, I can see that the proprty exists but I keep getting the error.

---

Yes a lot of questions have been asked about the issue in `bcrypt` which in most cases was caused by importing from `bcryptjs`.

I tried clearing both npm and yarn cache, deleted and reinstalled node_modules multiple times.

But they don't seem to work for `argon2` and `bcrypt` both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import * as argon2 from "argon2";

const hash = await argon2.hash(..);
```